# page links do not work properly

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, redirect, search, link

Some pages began to work incorrectly.

If I follow the `site.com/privacy-policy`

It redirects me to `site.com/search/privacy%20policy?amnoroute`

tell me how to fix

```
<?php
return [
    'modules' => [
        'Magento_Store' => 1,
        'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport' => 1,
        'Magento_Directory' => 1,
        'Magento_Amqp' => 1,
        'Magento_Config' => 1,
        'Magento_Theme' => 1,
        'Magento_Backend' => 1,
        'Magento_Variable' => 1,
        'Magento_Eav' => 1,
        'Magento_Search' => 1,
        'Magento_Backup' => 1,
        'Magento_Customer' => 1,
        'Magento_AdminNotification' => 1,
        'Magento_Authorization' => 1,
        'Magento_BundleImportExport' => 1,
        'Magento_CacheInvalidate' => 1,
        'Magento_Indexer' => 1,
        'Magento_Cms' => 1,
        'Magento_Security' => 1,
        'Magento_GraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogImportExport' => 1,
        'Magento_Catalog' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogInventory' => 1,
        'Magento_Rule' => 1,
        'Magento_Msrp' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogRule' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite' => 1,
        'Magento_StoreGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_Widget' => 1,
        'Magento_Quote' => 1,
        'Magento_SalesSequence' => 1,
        'Magento_Payment' => 1,
        'Magento_CmsGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite' => 1,
        'Magento_CmsUrlRewriteGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_User' => 1,
        'Magento_Sales' => 1,
        'Magento_Checkout' => 1,
        'Magento_EavGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_ConfigurableProduct' => 1,
        'Magento_Contact' => 1,
        'Magento_Cookie' => 1,
        'Magento_Cron' => 1,
        'Magento_CurrencySymbol' => 1,
        'Magento_Authorizenet' => 1,
        'Magento_Integration' => 1,
        'Magento_CustomerGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_CustomerImportExport' => 1,
        'Magento_Deploy' => 1,
        'Magento_Developer' => 1,
        'Magento_Dhl' => 1,
        'Magento_AsynchronousOperations' => 1,
        'Magento_DirectoryGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_Downloadable' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_ImportExport' => 1,
        'Magento_Bundle' => 1,
        'Magento_BundleGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogSearch' => 1,
        'Magento_AdvancedSearch' => 1,
        'Magento_Email' => 1,
        'Magento_EncryptionKey' => 1,
        'Magento_Fedex' => 1,
        'Magento_GiftMessage' => 1,
        'Magento_GoogleAdwords' => 1,
        'Magento_GoogleAnalytics' => 1,
        'Magento_Ui' => 1,
        'Magento_UrlRewriteGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_PageCache' => 1,
        'Magento_GroupedProduct' => 1,
        'Magento_GroupedImportExport' => 1,
        'Magento_GroupedCatalogInventory' => 1,
        'Magento_GroupedProductGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_DownloadableImportExport' => 1,
        'Magento_AuthorizenetAcceptjs' => 1,
        'Magento_InstantPurchase' => 1,
        'Magento_Analytics' => 1,
        'Magento_Inventory' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryAdminUi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryApi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryBundleProduct' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryCatalog' => 1,
        'Magento_InventorySales' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryCatalogApi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryConfiguration' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryElasticsearch' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryExportStockApi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryIndexer' => 1,
        'Magento_InventorySalesApi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryImportExport' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryCache' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryProductAlert' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryReservations' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryReservationCli' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryReservationsApi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryExportStock' => 1,
        'Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryShipping' => 1,
        'Magento_Shipping' => 1,
        'Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventorySourceSelection' => 1,
        'Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi' => 1,
        'Magento_LayeredNavigation' => 1,
        'Magento_Marketplace' => 1,
        'Magento_MediaStorage' => 1,
        'Magento_MessageQueue' => 1,
        'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport' => 1,
        'Magento_MsrpConfigurableProduct' => 1,
        'Magento_MsrpGroupedProduct' => 1,
        'Magento_Multishipping' => 1,
        'Magento_MysqlMq' => 1,
        'Magento_NewRelicReporting' => 1,
        'Magento_Newsletter' => 1,
        'Magento_OfflinePayments' => 1,
        'Magento_SalesRule' => 1,
        'Magento_GraphQlCache' => 1,
        'Magento_Vault' => 1,
        'Magento_Paypal' => 1,
        'Magento_Captcha' => 1,
        'Magento_PaypalCaptcha' => 1,
        'Magento_Persistent' => 1,
        'Magento_ProductAlert' => 1,
        'Magento_ProductVideo' => 1,
        'Magento_CheckoutAgreements' => 1,
        'Magento_QuoteAnalytics' => 1,
        'Magento_QuoteGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_ReleaseNotification' => 1,
        'Magento_Reports' => 1,
        'Magento_RequireJs' => 1,
        'Magento_Review' => 1,
        'Magento_ReviewAnalytics' => 1,
        'Magento_Robots' => 1,
        'Magento_Rss' => 1,
        'Magento_Elasticsearch' => 1,
        'MSP_ReCaptcha' => 1,
        'Magento_SalesAnalytics' => 1,
        'Magento_SalesGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_SalesInventory' => 1,
        'Magento_OfflineShipping' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable' => 1,
        'Magento_UrlRewrite' => 1,
        'Magento_Elasticsearch6' => 1,
        'Magento_CustomerAnalytics' => 1,
        'Magento_SendFriend' => 1,
        'Magento_SendFriendGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi' => 1,
        'Magento_Signifyd' => 1,
        'Magento_Sitemap' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_ConfigurableProductGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_Webapi' => 1,
        'Magento_SwaggerWebapi' => 1,
        'Magento_SwaggerWebapiAsync' => 1,
        'Magento_Swatches' => 1,
        'Magento_SwatchesGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation' => 1,
        'Magento_Tax' => 1,
        'Magento_TaxGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_TaxImportExport' => 1,
        'Magento_DownloadableGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_ThemeGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_Tinymce3' => 1,
        'Magento_Translation' => 1,
        'Magento_GoogleOptimizer' => 1,
        'Magento_Ups' => 1,
        'Magento_SampleData' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogUrlRewriteGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogAnalytics' => 1,
        'Magento_Usps' => 1,
        'Magento_ConfigurableProductSales' => 1,
        'Magento_Braintree' => 1,
        'Magento_VaultGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_Version' => 1,
        'Magento_Swagger' => 1,
        'Magento_WebapiAsync' => 1,
        'Magento_WebapiSecurity' => 1,
        'Magento_Weee' => 1,
        'Magento_WeeeGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogWidget' => 1,
        'Magento_Wishlist' => 1,
        'Magento_WishlistAnalytics' => 1,
        'Magento_WishlistGraphQl' => 1,
        'Amasty_AdvancedReview' => 1,
        'Amasty_Affiliate' => 1,
        'Amasty_Base' => 1,
        'Amasty_CronScheduleList' => 1,
        'Amasty_Groupcat' => 1,
        'Amasty_InvisibleCaptcha' => 1,
        'Amasty_Label' => 1,
        'Amasty_Mostviewed' => 1,
        'Amasty_PageSpeedOptimizer' => 1,
        'Amasty_ShippingTableRates' => 1,
        'Amasty_Xnotif' => 1,
        'Amasty_Xsearch' => 1,
        'Amazon_Core' => 1,
        'Amazon_Login' => 1,
        'Amazon_Payment' => 1,
        'Dotdigitalgroup_Email' => 1,
        'Firebear_ImportExport' => 1,
        'Firebear_ImportExportMsi' => 1,
        'Firebear_PlatformM1' => 1,
        'Klarna_Core' => 1,
        'Klarna_Ordermanagement' => 1,
        'Klarna_Kp' => 1,
        'Magento_PaypalReCaptcha' => 1,
        'MSP_TwoFactorAuth' => 1,
        'MageWorx_GeoIP' => 1,
        'MageWorx_CustomerLocation' => 1,
        'MageWorx_CustomerPrices' => 1,
        'MageWorx_CurrencySwitcher' => 1,
        'MageWorx_GeoLock' => 1,
        'MageWorx_SeoAll' => 1,
        'MageWorx_Info' => 1,
        'MageWorx_HtmlSitemap' => 1,
        'MageWorx_SeoBase' => 1,
        'MageWorx_SeoBreadcrumbs' => 1,
        'MageWorx_SeoCategoryGrid' => 1,
        'MageWorx_SeoCrossLinks' => 1,
        'MageWorx_SeoExtended' => 1,
        'MageWorx_SeoMarkup' => 1,
        'MageWorx_SeoRedirects' => 1,
        'MageWorx_SeoReports' => 1,
        'MageWorx_SeoUrls' => 1,
        'MageWorx_SeoXTemplates' => 1,
        'MageWorx_StoreSwitcher' => 1,
        'MageWorx_XmlSitemap' => 1,
        'Magedelight_Base' => 1,
        'Magedelight_Customerprice' => 1,
        'Mageplaza_Core' => 0,
        'Mirasvit_CacheWarmer' => 1,
        'Mirasvit_Core' => 1,
        'Mirasvit_Report' => 1,
        'Mollie_Payment' => 1,
        'OlegKoval_RegenerateUrlRewrites' => 1,
        'Rhs_Catalog' => 1,
        'Rhs_Cms' => 1,
        'Rhs_Minicart' => 1,
        'Rhs_NewsletterBlock' => 1,
        'Rhs_SuccessVideo' => 1,
        'Temando_Shipping' => 1,
        'TemplateMonster_AjaxCatalog' => 1,
        'TemplateMonster_AjaxCompare' => 1,
        'TemplateMonster_AjaxSearch' => 1,
        'TemplateMonster_AjaxWishlist' => 1,
        'TemplateMonster_Blog' => 1,
        'TemplateMonster_CatalogImagesGrid' => 1,
        'TemplateMonster_CountdownTimer' => 1,
        'TemplateMonster_FeaturedProduct' => 1,
        'TemplateMonster_FilmSlider' => 1,
        'TemplateMonster_GoogleMap' => 1,
        'TemplateMonster_ThemeOptions' => 1,
        'TemplateMonster_Megamenu' => 1,
        'TemplateMonster_NewsletterPopup' => 1,
        'TemplateMonster_Parallax' => 1,
        'TemplateMonster_SampleDataInstaller' => 1,
        'TemplateMonster_ShopByBrand' => 1,
        'TemplateMonster_SiteMaintenance' => 1,
        'TemplateMonster_SocialLogin' => 1,
        'TemplateMonster_SocialSharing' => 1,
        'TemplateMonster_LayoutSwitcher' => 1,
        'Vertex_Tax' => 1,
        'Zemez_Amp' => 1
    ]
];
```

Comment: Did you used any search extension? if so, there will be the option for 404 page redirect to search page

Comment: @Ranganathan when I go to site.com/search/, it redirects me to site.com/ and says that no products were found.

i used to advanced search by amasty

Comment: @Ranganathan I added my modules

Comment: Now Go to `Admin Panel → Stores → Configuration → Amasty Extensions → Advanced Search` In General tab change `Enable redirect From 404 to result page` to no

Comment: @Ranganathan 
I found a problem, it was in the turned off pages, ty

Comment: FYI: The above solution for 404 pages... 404 pages will redirect to search result page.